# Determine current code distribution by author

Tags: git

I thought it would be neat if it were possible to take a Git repository, run some script, and have it generate the number of lines in the code base, and the proportion of each author that contributed to it.

Basically, because I am kind of a competitive coder, I would like a personal metric to see if the number of lines that I've written (in the current HEAD) are greater than my partner(s). It would be a fun statistic to say "I wrote % of the current codebase".

Has anyone ever thought to do this? I've looked for a way, but my shell scripting is not the best, so I couldn't do it alone.

Comment: I'm sure you've heard this one before: "Measuring programming progress by lines of code is like measuring aircraft building progress by weight."

Comment: @Etaoin: wish I could +1000 that. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use git log, as illustrated in "[Which Git commit stats are easy to pull](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1487421/6309)".

Or you can have a look at Git [Lookatgit](https://github.com/mpdehaan/lookatgit) project, which does inspect the number of lines changed, as seen in its [`gitauthor.rb` class](https://github.com/mpdehaan/lookatgit/blob/master/gitauthor.rb).

Answer (score 1):

You could try to parse the output of [`git-blame`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/git-blame). This command gives the last person that edited each line of a file.

This example is not exactly what you want but I think it gives you the idea:

```
git blame -e the/file | awk -F '<|>' '{print $2}' | sort | uniq -c
```

This will print the e-mail addresses of the authors together with the number of lines they modified lastly for a file, for example:

```
     47 foo@bar.com
  34712 blah@baz.com
```

To make it run on the whole repository, you can do something like this:

```
git ls-files | while read f; do git blame -e $f; done | awk -F '<|>' '{print $2}' | sort | uniq -c
```

The idea here is to first generate the list of files with git ls-files, and then run the above snippet on each of the files (using the snippet mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6566602/1298153)). If you're running this on a large codebase, you may want to store intermediate results in temporary files rather than use pipes.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need [gitdm](https://www.gitorious.org/mining-tools/gitdm), it can do exactly what you need. We use it for Mahara project to produce [contribution statistics](https://mahara.org/interaction/forum/topic.php?id=4469).

Just do what README suggests:

> A typical command line used to generate the "who write 2.6.x" LWN
>   articles looks like:
>
> ```
> git log -p -M v2.6.19..v2.6.20 |  gitdm -u -s -a -o results -h results.html
> ```

You can also customise it for your own purposes.